# Toggle form Validators in Angular 4/5

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, validation, angular-forms

I want to be able to *temporarily* disable validation for the entire form. Note: I don't want to disable the actual form though...

The closest I can find is to manually [remove and add them as described here](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators), but this is quite awkward for complex forms.

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)
  ])]
});
```

Is there anything similar to this?:

```
this.form.disableValidators() // ???
```

Comment: temporarily means when you want validation to be added

Comment: yes, remove and re-add at a later point

Comment: when you want to re add

Comment: Basically toggle with a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean property in your component.

```
validationEnabled = true;
```

Then, when you define your controls,

```
emailValidators = Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email]);
passwordValidators = Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8);

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', this.validationEnabled ? emailValidators : null],
      password: ['', this.validationEnabled ? passwordValidators : null]
});
```

And set the property however you like.

A downside to this approach is that you will need to rebuild the form when you want to toggle.

If you want to do it after the form is created, you'll need to use the methods in the API you linked above https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators.

Comment: nice, but I'm trying to toggle. A ternary operator will evaluate straight away

Comment: *after the form is created, dynamically

Comment: Correct, unfortunately with this approach you would need to recreate the form constantly. I edited my answer to reflect that. You will have to use the API you linked in your question to do this after the form is created.  : / While it can be difficult with a complex form, it's a nice API and you can use it to make the code simple. It may require some serious thought, however.

Comment: guess I have to traverse all my nested form groups so and create a map myself?

Comment: Something like that :)

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm new to angular, but would it be possible/appropriate to create a directive for this? It seems like a generic enough use case that it could be used elsewhere.  ```[disableValidation]="someBoolean"```.

Comment: Perhaps, I guess I would need more context to answer that. Like, should the parent be the one who tells the form when to ignore validation or should the form itself know when it should ignore validation? I think that's outside the scope of this question, though. I'd recommend giving it your best shot and if you run into trouble, create a separate question with a Stackblitz or Plunkr reproduction. Good luck :)